# Mariadb Vb .net Stored procedure error inserting Column cannot be null

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, mariadb, sql-insert

I'm playing around with RFID and to learn the technology i bought a RC522. Connected it to a raspberry pi and started building an app.

When trying to register a tag to a mariadb database it is failing. I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE RFID.Users (
  ID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Fname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  Lname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  TAG VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  Image LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 4,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 16384,
CHARACTER SET latin1,
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'%'
PROCEDURE RFID.Write_Tag(IN `@Fname` VARCHAR(100), IN `@Lname` VARCHAR(100), IN `@Tag` VARCHAR(100), IN `@Image` LONGBLOB)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO 
  Users 
  (Fname, Lname, TAG, Image)
  VALUES  
  (@Fname, @Lname, @Tag, @Image);
END
```

Vb.net code to insert tags:

```
Private Sub BtnWriteTag_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWriteTag.Click

        Try
            If IsNothing(PictureBox1.Image) Then
                MsgBox("Please load image first")
            Else
                lblinfo.Text = "Please place your tag near the reader"
                sshcmd = sshClient.RunCommand("python /home/pi/fabio/workingwriter.py " & "'" & txtFname.Text & "'")
                txtTag.Text = sshcmd.Result.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")
                Dim filesize As UInt32
                Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
                PictureBox1.Image.Save(mstream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
                filesize = mstream.Length
                mstream.Close()
                MessageBox.Show(filesize)
                MessageBox.Show(txtFname.Text)
                con = GetConnect()
                con.Open()
                cmd = New MySqlCommand("Write_Tag", con) With {
                        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    }
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", txtFname.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", txtLname.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TAG", txtTag.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", arrImage)
                Dim x As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                If x = 1 Then
                    MessageBox.Show(" User saved.")
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error found: " & vbCrLf & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "RFID Tag Reader")
        Finally
            If cmd IsNot Nothing Then cmd.Dispose()
            If con IsNot Nothing AndAlso con.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

The error i'm getting back from the try catch is: "Column 'Fname' cannot be null"

Appreciate your help,

Fabio

Comment: You can either allow `null` values in the table, or use a default value. What do you want to do?

Comment: They can't be null because I'm parsing them. But there is an ID auto incremental and somehow I believe that's causing the error. I send values for all columns so getting nulls shouldn't be the result.

Comment: Call the sproc with MySql workbench/heidisqlmor similar to prove if it's the vb or the sproc

Comment: Enhance your exception handling by adding `ex.ToString()` and maybe you'll get some more details about the error.

Comment: at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: @CaiusJard Perfect. It worked. Thanks for the help guys. Appreciate it

Comment: I'll put as an answer you can accept so others will know it's not a problem any more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your use of @ symbols on parameters everywhere - I'm not totally certain it is the problem but I've never seen it used for Maria.

Maria sproc params don't have @ before the name, in the docs.

Remove it from the AddWithValue call too:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'%'
PROCEDURE RFID.Write_Tag(
  IN pFname VARCHAR(100),
  IN pLname VARCHAR(100),
  IN pTag VARCHAR(100), 
  IN pImage LONGBLOB)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO 
  Users 
  (Fname, Lname, TAG, Image)
  VALUES  
  (pFname, pLname, pTag, pImage);
END

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pFname", txtFname.Text)
...
```